# Thread safe pthread mutex lock wrappers

Tags: function, locking, thread-safety, posix, mutex

I am writing a OS abstraction library for which i want to write wrappers for pthread mutex over Linux.

This code shall be called by multiple threads.

The code goes something like this:

```
int my_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    return pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
}
```

1. Will the function my_lock also will be thread-safe?
2. If not, How to make it thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you posted as your function:

```
int my_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) 
{ 
    return pthread_mutex_lock(mutex); 
}
```

Why do you even need the function here?

The code is thread-safe as you have presented it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a nested function call.. 
Instead of returning the pthread_mutex_lock, it can be used straight away in the routine. This will reduce the execution time avoiding jump instruction from one function to another.